# Can't implement ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, mobile, view, scrollview

I am having a problem implementing `ScrollView`.

Here is what I have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.migiapp.justjava.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Toppings"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:text="Whipped cream"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Quantitiy"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:onClick="decrement"
                    android:text="-" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:onClick="increment"
                    android:text="+" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Order Summary"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="$0"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="submitOrder"
                android:text="Order" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I get a constrain error, which I had before the `ScrollView`. All I did was infer constraints in linear layout and the problem was fixed. Here whether I infer constraints or not, nothing is visible.

Comment: paste the error log

Answer (score 0):

Your View hierarchy is a little bit mixed up. You `LinearLayout` is inside the `ScrollView` which is correct. But the `attributes` for the `constraintLayout` are misplaced here. These `attributes` must be inside the `ScrollView`. Also, I guess you need to set `height` and `width` of `LinearLayout` higher than `0dp`. Maybe like this:

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
          >
```